# Traces.svclog in C drive

Tags: wcf, windows-8, trace

I'm using Windows 8. In drive C 's root directory (C:) there are 27 WCF Trace file; 26 of them are named like <guid>Traces.svclog and one is Traces.svclog. I'm trying to find out which applications are creating these files; because I don't have any application that uses wcf trace described [here](http://dotnetrobert.com/?q=node/63).

And here is my C:\ directory's view:
[image: svclog files view]

I've looked all of the traces: there are only 2 unique trace and the rest is exact copies of them. Here comes the details from one of them;

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>589828</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-10-15T06:37:57.4222685Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host" ProcessID="7104" ThreadID="78" />
<Channel />
<Computer>MYCOMP</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-TR/library/System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebHostCompilation.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>ASP.Net hosted compilation.</Description>
<AppDomain>7f594460-3-129947566686622036</AppDomain>
<Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceParser/17864371</Source>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/StringTraceRecord">
<VirtualPath>/BI/DataService.svc</VirtualPath>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

So the C:\ directory is filling with rubbish traces. I've installed WCF&WF samples, and maybe that caused this. Can you help me on this; to find out which application is doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Search your drive for app.config files that have systems.diagnostics sections that enable trace on the system.servicemodel tracesource.